I am trying to check if a word exists in the English dictionary using C# on .NET
I am currently using NetSpell but I am running into many FileNotFound exceptions when I run the code:
NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling spellCheck = new NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling(); 
spellCheck.Dictionary = dict; 

if (!spellCheck.TestWord(wordIn)) 
{ 
    return false; 
} 

return true;

Any idea where I am going wrong? The library does now initialise correctly (had a couple of issues with that before), I am open to suggestions for other libraries as well as potential fixes :) TIA.

Which line is throwing the exception?

What library are you using? The one on NuGet was had a single release 10 years ago and was abandoned. It's unclear if it contains any dictionaries or if you have to provide them yourself. Right now we can't even guess what line is throwing. At the very least post the full exception text (including the call stack), not just the name and explain which package you used

open to suggestions SO isn't a recommendation site. At the very least try searching for spell in NuGet. Some of these packages are clients for cloud services like Azure because that's what most applications use nowadays, especially mobile apps.

I managed to solve this problem with symspell. Download it from nuget, then use this code:
var symSpell = new SymSpell();

string dictionaryPath = "frequency_dictionary_en_82_765.txt";
symSpell.LoadDictionary(dictionaryPath, 0, 1);

var suggestions = symSpell.Lookup("YOUR WORD", SymSpell.Verbosity.Closest, 1);

if (suggestions[0].distance == 0)
{
    // word found !
}
else
{
    // word not found
}

By installing the package it will put 2 txt files in your project. Move them into the folder of the executable file. (bin/Debug/net8.0/)
